# Secure cloud functions in Parse from iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, security, google-app-engine, parse-platform

**TLDR:** All I want to do is secure my cloud function in Parse so that it only accepts requests from my iOS app. How can I do that?

**Longer version:**

I recently got started with using Parse for a client side app I'm building using a Google API.

Before using Parse, my issue was that the Google API calls from my app were not secure. I tried a Man in the middle attack on my app, and I was able to successfully get the bundle id and app id (Google claims some form of security is achieved by ensuring that the call is from the correct bundle id that you can specify on their console). So despite using SSL, seems like it was easy to get this information. Now this Google API is paid, so someone could easily abuse my key when I release my app and raise my bills.

I was anyways also thinking of doing some lightweight work in the backend, so I figured to use Parse. Now the call to the Google API is done in Cloud Code. But a new problem I'm facing is how to secure calls to the Cloud function I've defined in Parse? The Parse [App ID and Client Key aren't secure at all](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-i-are-you-the-key-master/).

All of Parse's blogs keep talking about creating users and defining ACLs etc. But in my case, there is no data in my Parse app and there is no user per se. It simply calls the Google API and returns the result. All I want to do is secure my cloud function so that it only accepts requests from my iOS app. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inherent security risk here is that any key you store in your app is vulnerable, for that reason encryption is also vulnerable. My recommendation is to use the automatic user in Parse on your iOS app, you could even throttle excessive requests/abuse by a single user. By creating and using a user you are able to gain the benefits of ACL which appears the best security option available in Parse currently. At that point you send the automatic user in your cloud code request and verify it's a valid iOS user.

Comment: Yup, totally agree with your first point. As for using automatic user, I'll first have to call save on the user right? And I don't quite understand how ACL's apply for the automatic user in this case since there's no object access, just function access. The way I understand it: I should create the automatic user, set something custom on that user object, do a PFCloud request with that user, and then check in my cloud function if the user has that custom setting. But then how would that prevent anyone from seeing that custom setting?

Comment: Automatic user creates a unique user for that device. After which you can use it just like a normal user except no login. You then pass the unique user in requests to your cloud code and limit responses to something reasonable or take other security measures.

Comment: Ahh, that makes a ton of sense. From my research, seems like the current user should automatically be passed in to PFCloud requests. But I don't think that's happening. I see request.user is null in the function. Any thoughts? This is how I'm making the request: `PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("<endpoint>", withParameters: [<params_dict>], block: {(result) -> Void in
    print(result)
})`

Comment: Ah for that I don't know. I haven't used cloud code yet. Just the rest api and Android/iOS sdks.

Comment: :( Alright. I'm unmarking your answer as correct for now. So that others who come here don't leave thinking my question is resolved. Thanks for the clarification though

Comment: That's better asked as a separate questions and considered better etiquette. I told you how to secure your cloud code not pass a user to it.

Comment: In the api you usually pass the current user as a parameter where it's needed.

Comment: That's fair. Thanks a lot. I'll post a separate question for passing user.